# Is my collection secure?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I removed both insecure and autopublish packages from my project. but i put my collection in the "/lib" to be accessed by both the client and the server, because am inserting the values from the client.

when i type "db.collectionName.find().fetch()" from the console, i can see the documents inside the collection.

are there any way i can disable this? i know about publish and subscribe, but i will have to put the collection on the server side if am not mistaken and i need it to be in "/lib" so that i can insert the values.

this is my collection:

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection("products");

Products.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  //collection elements
}));
```

and to allow insert, update, and remove packages:

```
Products.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc){
    return true;
  },
  update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){
    return true;
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc){
    return true;
  }
});
```

and am using quickForm to insert the details

```
{{> quickForm collection="Products" id="submitPostForm"
  type="insert" doc=doc}}
```

and an AutoForm.hooks to insert the URLs that i am getting from the user before he submits the quick form. it is located in the "/client" folder

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    submitPostForm: {  //<--- this is the id of your form
        before: {  //<-- before submit
            insert: function (doc) {  //<-- get the doc to be submitted

                //some values will be inserted in the collection before submitting
            }
        },
        onSuccess: function (formType, result) {

        },
        onError: function (formType, error) {

        }
    }
});
```

Am using template to find all the items in the collection to list them in the client, "because i want to display all the documents in my collection in the Home Page."

```
Template.list_products.helpers({
     applications:function(){
      return Products.find({});
      }
    });
```

How to not allow the users to fetch the collection data from the console?

Comment: @Kyll I updated my question, included my collection, and how the information are inserted in the collection, let me know if there are any further information i should provide as well, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for that edit. Could you try and make your example Minimal (see [mcve])? The schema for example seems to contain a lot of fields which aren't necessary to reproduce or understand your issue, the same goes for the `before.insert` hook.

Comment: @Kyll, thanks, i reduced the code and added the helper am using to find all the documents in the collection. in the template am using {{#each}} to loop through them all and display them in the client

Comment: There's still a missing piece. If you removed `autopublish` then clients should not see all data in the collection. Do you have some pub/sub code?

Comment: @Kyll i removed it but the user still can fetch the documents of the collection from the web console. mind if i ask, do i need pub/sub when my collection is in lib directory? sorry because am beginner

Comment: In that case you're probably also populating the collection in a shared directory.

Comment: @Kyll yes, because am inserting the documents from the client, is it possible to make it secure without moving it to the server side only?

Comment: If you are inserting the documents from the client, it means that the client already has the data. Why would you want to hide it?

Comment: I also don't see why you would want to prevent users from **fetching** the collection in the console ( since your already displaying some of this data in your template). You should however be concerned with allowing users to **write** to mongo from the console.

Comment: @chackerian how do i disable writing from the console?

Comment: @Kyll am concerned about deleting and writing to the collection from the console, thats the reason i want to hide it

Answer (score 0):

You can put the collection in the `/lib`, the publish in `/server` and subscribe in `/client` so that both client and server know about the collection existence and logic, but only the server controls what gets sent. When you say console, do you refer to `meteor shell` from the terminal, or the web console?

I don't think the browser console can see documents that have not been published, but I'm not sure how the `allow` change that. I personally prefer to only use meteor methods to change the collection.

Comment: am referring to the web console, and i don't have publish and subscribe, do i still need them if my collection in the "/lib" directory?